# comparing against slick.lifted.Rep[java.sql.Timestamp]

Tags: scala, slick

I have the next command:

```
         def myfunction(depIDs: Option[String], iniDate: Option[String] ....

               val iniDateValue = Timestamp.valueOf(iniDate.get)
               ..........
             ........
                       ai <- AppointmentItems.table if ((ai.projectService === prjs.id.getOrElse("NULL")) && (ai.start.get.before(iniDateValue  ))) 
         ........
```

'start' is a field declared as

```
        start: Option[java.sql.Timestamp
```

We are using Slick.
I got the error

```
          value before is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[java.sql.Timestamp]
```

as I am trying to see if  ai.start   is before  iniDateValue.

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ai.start.get < iniDateValue
```

instead of

```
ai.start.get.before(iniDateValue)
```